# How to seperate the string of the variable in PHP from requested word

Tags: php, string

```
 $t = ABCDEFPN03KSASDEID;
 $r = stristr($t, 'PN03', true);

 My Value is $r = ABCDEF
 and in if condition while i plan to seperate it throws output wrong
 But i want output $s = PNO3KSASDEID like this
```

My code:
(I used variable as my own)

```
$r = stristr($t, 'PN03', true);
if( ($s = substr($t, 'PNO3', false)) == true) {
    $s = stristr($t, 'PNO3', false);
    print_r($s);
}
```

output: PN03KSASDEID is needed.

Please suggest me solution.

Answer (score 1):

Get in the habit of encapsulating your behaviours in reusable functions

```
function str_split_term($string, $term) {
  $pos = strpos($string, $term);
  if ($pos === false)
    return $string;
  else
    return substr($string, $pos);
}
```

Your use case

```
echo str_split_term('ABCDEFPN03KSASDEID', 'PN03'); // PN03KSASDEID
```

If the term is not found in the string, the string will output unaltered

```
echo str_split_term('ABCDEFPN03KSASDEID', 'ZZZ'); // ABCDEFPN03KSASDEID
```

---

**PHP7**

If you're are using a current version of PHP, I suggest you add type hints to the function

```
function str_split_term(string $string, string $term): string {
  $pos = strpos($string, $term);
  if ($pos === false)
    return $string;
  else
    return substr($string, $pos);
}
```